# Electric traiction work

Tags: power-supply, voltage

In railway traction only one line is on over head of the train of 25k ac. Which is single phase, where is another line? To give supply to train? How it works? Which motor is best for traction?

Comment: Google is your friend. [**Try this**](http://www.railenergy.eu/RailenergyMethodology.aspx)

Comment: I searched in google, it shows that, track itself acts as return conductor. How it works? I cant get this.. I too try this to search on youtube, but i cant get which relates to my question

Comment: @user83853 It is clearly shown in the picture that every rail segment is coupled to the current return conductor at regular intervals. The return conductor is connected at the substation transformer for the rail-line. The current travels through the body of the train to the track through the wheels and then down the track to the current return. Other systems can use a dedicated neutral conductor, but a single coupling is less prone to failure than maintaining two couplings

Comment: The track is made out of metal, you know. It is just like a wire. Why is that hard to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The running rails are the return path for the traction current. This means that expansion gaps have to be bridged with links capable of passing the current. It also means that signalling systems which use the shorting out of the running rails by the train have to be immune to components of the traction currents in the same frequency band, or to put it the other way round, traction drive systems have to limit their currents in the signalling bands.

The motor never runs at 25kV, that is not practicable for the insulation system of a motor. The 25kV line runs through a vacuum circuit breaker and into a transformer which steps the voltage down to a suitable level for the drive system and motors. DC motors were used widely before the invention of variable frequency drives, and they have certain inherent characteristics which make them suitable for traction use, but also the disadvantage of brushes which wear out and are affected by water and debris. The modern approach uses induction motors to avoid brush problems, but the drive electronics has to be much more sophisticated.